Sort a list of objects based on the index of the object's property from another list
I have a tuple, RELAY_PINS that holds GPIO pin numbers in the order that the relays are installed.  RELAY_PINS is immutable, and its ordering does not change, while the order that the devices are defined in changes frequently.
The MRE:
from random import shuffle, randint

class Device:
    def __init__(self, pin_number):
        self.pin_number = pin_number

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pin_number)

RELAY_PINS = ( 14, 15, 18, 23, 24, 25, 1, 12, 16, 20, 21, 26, 19, 13, 6, 5 )

def MRE():
    devices = [ Device(pin) for pin in RELAY_PINS ]

    # the ordering for the list of devices should be considered random for the sake of this question
    shuffle(devices)
    return devices

My solution "works", but frankly, it's embarrassing:
def main():
    devices = MRE()
    pin_map = { pin_number : index for index, pin_number in enumerate(RELAY_PINS) }

    ordered_devices = [ None for _ in range(len(RELAY_PINS)) ]

    for device in devices:
        index = pin_map[device.pin_number]
        ordered_devices[index] = device

    return [ dev for dev in ordered_devices if dev is not None ]

I know there is a better solution, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.
What is the pythonic solution to this problem?

What is embarrassing about this rather straightforward and clear code?

@mkrieger1 because I knew there was a 1 liner solution and I could not see it.

Are the pins in each list unique, or can there be duplicates?

You can use sorted with a key function:
from random import randint, shuffle


class Device:

  def __init__(self, pin_number: int):
    self.pin_number = pin_number

  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return str(self.pin_number)

  def __repr__(self) -> str:
    return f'Device(pin_number={self.pin_number})'


RELAY_PINS: tuple[int, ...] = (14, 15, 18, 23, 24, 25, 1, 12, 16, 20, 21, 26,
                               19, 13, 6, 5)


def MRE() -> None:
  devices = [Device(pin) for pin in RELAY_PINS]
  devices.pop(randint(0, len(RELAY_PINS) - 1))
  shuffle(devices)
  return devices


def main() -> None:
  devices = MRE()
  ordered_devices = sorted(devices, key=lambda d: RELAY_PINS.index(d.pin_number))
  print(ordered_devices)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

Example Output (device with pin_number=12 randomly popped):
[Device(pin_number=14), Device(pin_number=15), Device(pin_number=18), Device(pin_number=23), Device(pin_number=24), Device(pin_number=25), Device(pin_number=1), Device(pin_number=16), Device(pin_number=20), Device(pin_number=21), Device(pin_number=26), Device(pin_number=19), Device(pin_number=13), Device(pin_number=6), Device(pin_number=5)]


If the list being sorted is large, it would be best to convert RELAY_PINS into a dictionary that maps each pin number to its index, and use that in the key function.

@Barmar Would that really be best? Wouldn't the question's solution be better?

@nocomment I'm just saying it's better than calling .index() in the key function, since that's O(n) time.

You're not the only audience here, this answer is intended for everyone with similar problems. @LordElrond
